# spring boot not finding Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot application with the following structure

```
Main Application 
 com/my/application/app/boot/AppStarter.java
 depends on Lib Application

Lib Application
 META-INF/package/persistence.xml
 com/my/application/data/Entity1.java
```

Where Entity 1 is a persistence object using `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations

AppStarter is as follows:

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.my.application.sampleScan1",
        "com.my.application.sampleScan2"})
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.my.application.data"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:test.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:my/application/fake/fakeContext.xml"})
public class FakeAppBooter {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(FakeAppBooter.class, args);
}
}
```

When I package this using the spring boot application as a jar, The Lib Application is within the `/lib/LibApplication.jar` , however when it tries to access the Entity `Entity1`, I get an:  `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.my.application.data.Entity1`

When this is executed from within eclipse, this works fine, it only breaks when i run the spring-boot-plugin generated jar.

Comment: Same boat. Got any paddles?

Comment: This has been ages and i do not remember what the actual issue was. What i do remember is that Spring boot annotation and xml configuration did not work well together. If you can try to switch to annotation-only or xml-only configuration it might help.

Comment: I was missing @EntityScan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the annotations individually, the best practice is just to use

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

To annotate your class, and let Spring Boot do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need component scan for all your packages and entity scan for all your entities

com.uganda.** and com.uganda.**.entity

all should be included in your boot application class as follows

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @ComponentScan({ "com.uganda"})
 @EntityScan(basePackages= {"com.uganda"})
 public class MyBootpApplication {
```